# Regarding code conversion from VB6 to jQuery

Tags: jquery, vb6

I have a condition in `VB6` as:

```
If (CheckNullInteger(ApptData.Recordset.Fields("VisitId")) +
    CheckNullInteger(ApptData.Recordset.Fields("RequestId"))) > 0
```

I want to write in `jQuery`. Can anyone help me?

Comment: How are you supposed to be able to access a DB recordset from a client-side library like jQuery? You must elaborate on your question.

Comment: Just to be clear, jQuery is for manipulating DOM. I _think_ what you're asking is how do you check if a value is null in Javascript?

Comment: The tags `.net` and `vb.net` are not relevant here.

Comment: Here Just I want to add the length of the two values(like VisitID and RequestID) then checking whether the value is greather than zero or not..

Comment: If you want to add two values and check whether the result is greater than zero in Javascript it would just be `if ( VisitID + RequestID > 0 )` Have you tried that? What happened? What did you want to happen?